# Проблема с slideToggle

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

https://youtu.be/NaqEx12tz_g
Видео с проблемой!

Проблема состоит в том что при нажатия на кнопку меню не должна пропадать!

```js
 $( "#clickmee" ).click(function() {
  $( "#hov_menu" ).slideToggle( "slow", function() {
  });
});
```

Comment: Попробуйте таким образом, тут идет блокировка действия браузера на ссылку.
`$( "#clickmee" ).click(function(e) {
  $( "#hov_menu" ).slideToggle( "slow", function() {
});
 e.preventDefault();
});`

Comment: Пасиб сработала!

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$(".nav_btn").click(function() {
    $(this).next().slideToggle();
});
```

Попробуй поставить !important еще

Comment: куда в этом коде надо поставить `!important`? :)